# Window controls not updating when going to next object in observablecollection

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection of my quiz question class object. I have "Next" button, and want to bind the window controls to a specific Question object in that collection. The binding seems to work (textbox is populated correctly initially), but when I click Next, which DOES populate my currQuestion object correctly, the textbox does not update to display the current question, it continues to display the original question.
I've stripped down the xaml and code-behind as much as possible to make it easier to debug, and yes I know I should be using mvvm so let me know if that's part of the problem. Here's my xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Quiz.QuizMaintWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Quiz"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="QuizMaintWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid Name="grd1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" MinWidth="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Name="txtQuestion" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Question}"/>
    <Button Name="btnNext" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Next" Margin="5" Click="btnNext_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Here's my code-behind

```
    public partial class QuizMaintWindow : Window
{
    private clsQuestionAnswer qa;  // this is the current question to be displayed
    private ObservableCollection<clsQuestionAnswer> questions;
    private int questionIndex = 0;

    public QuizMaintWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GetTopicQuestions();
        grd1.DataContext = qa;
    }

    private void GetTopicQuestions()
    {
        questions = clsData.GetTopicQuestions(10);
        qa = questions[questionIndex];                             
    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        qa = questions[++questionIndex];
        // MessageBox.Show(qa.Question);
    }
}
```

and here's the question class

```
   public class clsQuestionAnswer: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int questionId;
    private int topicId;
    private string question;
    private string answer;
    private bool ignore;

    public int QuestionId
    {
        get { return questionId; }
        set
        {
            questionId = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("QuestionId");
        }
    }

    public int TopicId
    {
        get { return topicId; }
        set
        {
            topicId = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TopicId");
        }
    }

    public string Question
    {
        get { return question; }
        set
        {
            question = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Question");
        }
    }

    public string Answer
    {
        get { return answer; }
        set
        {
            answer = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Answer");
        }
    }

    public bool Ignore
    {
        get { return ignore; }
        set
        {
            ignore = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Ignore");
        }            
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You did not update the `grd1.DataContext` when you change `qa`. It will not happen automagically

Comment: My apologies for answering myself, but as far as I can tell Sir Rufos comment didn't appear to be an answer, there was no checkmark for me to click to accept it, there were only two icons to the left of his comment - the up arrow and the flag, and that's how it still looks. It just looked like a comment with no way to accept it. It still looks that way. I'll  look into the help more to see what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inform the page or grid that the underlying data has changed. So in the button code add this:

```
grd1.DataContext = qa = questions[++questionIndex];
```

and no that code is not a typo, one can do multiple assignments towards an end value.